# DXA Json files | Who is what

Tags: dxa, web8, sdl-tridion, dxa-2.0

At the below path of the DXA web application:

```
BinaryData/<PUBLICATION_ID>/??/System/Config

BinaryData/<PUBLICATION_ID>/??/System/mappings

BinaryData/<PUBLICATION_ID>/??/System/resources
```

I see various JSON file such as: `_all.json`, `core.json`, `resources.json` and few others.

Can you please help me understand the purpose of each of these JSON file?
Also, which Template/Page/Component publishing results in these JSON files being created?

UPDATE 1:
Below JSON files I can see in broker DB:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_all.json` files hold references to other files, but can have additional data (like in the case of \system\cinfig_all.json)

> BinaryData/PUBLICATION_ID/??/System/mappings

These files contain information which is needed by the framework to perform the semantic mapping when creating viewmodels.

> BinaryData/PUBLICATION_ID/??/System/resources

These files contain your resources (ie. labels) which are defined in components which are linked to the Module Configuration component of your module

> BinaryData/PUBLICATION_ID/??/System/Config

These files contain your configuration entries which are, similarly to the resource components, defined in components which are linked to the Module Configuration component of your module

> Also, which Template/Page/Component publishing results in these JSON files being created ?

Strictly speaking, none :). That is, these files are created from the broker DB for a certain publication when you access one of its published pages. The mechanism how the content ends up in the broker is by publishing the `_System\Publish Settings` Page. Once you do that, you can obtain new values by using the `/admin/refresh` endpoint, because these files are not being recreated on every request.

Comment: In the broker DB i cannot see files like: core.json or even _all.json. I have attached an Image of what I see in DB.

Comment: Also, I have faced errors like: "item system/config/_all.json not found for localization '5'" I am confused, if JSON is in DB, why the DXA is looking for the JSON on file system ?

Answer (score 1):

Atila already explained the purpose of those JSON files pretty well.

Regarding where you find them in the Broker DB: these JSON files are published as Binaries (check your BINARY_VARIANTS table).

In the DXA Web Application, such items are called Static Content Items and they are cached on file system to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks Rick for the info on where to look into DB. That was really helpful