# Why can be set to false flag "IsXpmEnabled" only on live site?

Tags: dxa

Why can be set to false flag `IsXpmEnabled` only on live site (staging is always true)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't fully understand what exactly you are asking, but if it's how the `IsXpmEnabled` works in DXA and how to change it, then find the answer below. If not, please rephrase the question and include any additional details like which issues you are facing.

The `IsXpmEnabled` is a property on the `Localization` class and is set based on `staging` key from the `BinaryData\publication_ID\config\_all.json` file, see below.

[image]

The `_all.json` file gets created when you do a `Publish Settings` and access the wbsite, see question [DXA Json files | Who is what](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20790/dxa-json-files-who-is-what) for more details.

During rendering of said page, the Tridion Topology is checked whether the CD environment you are publishing to has the preview capability registered. If yes, then it's assumed that it's a Staging website and XPM should be enabled, so the json is created accordingly.

Comment: Correct. The term “staging” in the JSON file is legacy. As Atila explained, it is set to `true` if the CD Environment has a Preview Capability, meaning it is XPM Enabled. In that case, DXA will output XPM markup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It was very useful to me.