# Configuration issue with core.json and not found /system/config/core.json

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

When new Dxa website 'abc' is started it is looking for Core.json file (in BinaryData\tcm-99\system\config\core.json).
When I copy it myself to that location it works.

Which Component/Page/configuration is responsible for that name? I aspect to use abc.json.

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: DxaItemNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Item '/system/config/core.json' not found for Localization '99'
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Providers.Binary.GraphQLBinaryProvider.GetBinary(Localization localization, String urlPath)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Statics.BinaryFileManager.GetCachedFile(String urlPath, Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetStaticContentItem(String urlPath, Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationResources.LoadConfigSection(String sectionName)
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationResources.<GetConfigValue>b__6_0(String k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.LocalizationResources.GetConfigValue(String key)
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetConfigValue(String key)
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Models.PageModel.GetXpmMarkup(Localization localization)
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaPageMarkup(HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Git\xxx\xxx\Site.abc\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:line 31
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<RenderPageCore>b__0(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

**UPDATE-1**:
Core 'lean' solved it for me (see below). Localisation component here is the same as other module.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit simplified, but, when you publish the `Publish Settings` Page, it goes through all your active "Module Configuration" Components and creates a binary for them which end up in the broker. Once the DXA website is started, it downloads (caches) said jsons into the `Binary Data` folder. See also [DXA Json files | Who is what](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20790/dxa-json-files-who-is-what)

Now the issue might be that the core.json is needed even though if you are not using any of its features. I have run into such scenarios, for example the Page XPM markup specifically looks for a settings from the core.json file.

Comment: We are not using XPM. Is there a method to disable it (in web.config)? Maybe that is resolved then.

Comment: The `@Html.DxaPageMarkup()` on the layout view is what accesses the previously mentioned setting, but as I've said, there might be additional references to the core module.

Comment: Indeed, the `Core.json` config file is needed even if you don’t use the Core Module (this is where Framework / Core Module separation is not ideal yet). See, for example the  `Localization.Load` implementation: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Common/Configuration/Localization.cs